# how to capture SOAP request from client side?

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

I have a C# client application that works with a web service using SOAP request. I've generate the requests C# code from the services web address using VS05 WSDL. I want the client in case of an error to print to a log file the SOAP request and response.
It's need to be done in run time.

how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check the [following blog post](http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx) for an example of writing a custom SoapExtension that will allow you to achieve this.

Comment: I've tried following the example in the link above, but I'm getting the following error when ever I try to instantiate a SOAP service:"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.".
It worked before the changes...

Comment: @RoeeGavirel, can you capture the reason of the exception? Maybe the InnerException will contain more useful information about the issue?

Comment: Thanks, That worked. I had to copy the dll of the SoapExtention file to the same folder as the exe. for some reason just adding the dll to the assembly folder didn't do it.